# (boonex dolphin) disallow same sex contact

Tags: boonex-dolphin

I've a dating site developed with Boonex Dolphin and I want to disallow all contact with members who are the same sex.

For example, in search page, if members is a male for example, he can see only women.

Does someone know what files have to be modified for doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `BxBaseTemplSearchProfile` file to write the condition to get the expected results